# How to put value from next row from latter on

Tags: sql-server, date, group-by

I search a lot but didn't find any thing related to my query. what I was looking for is I want to add date from my next row into latter row. For example:

```
cusnbr name  loadnumber  date
 1      A       10       20100101
 1      A       20       20110101
 1      B       30       20120101  *
 2      C       40       20130101
 2      D       50       20140101  *
```

What I was looking is like below output:

```
cusnbr name  loadnumber  date
 1      A       20       20120101
 2      C       40       20140101
```

Date of * but record from previous on the basis of changed name for a particular customer. Their are million of customer, its just a example I put it here. what approach should I follow or any code that can help me would be great !!

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit of a weird query, but I think this is along the lines you are looking for?

First I make a temporary copy of your test data:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (cusnbr INT, name CHAR(1), loadnumber INT, [date] DATE);
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1, 'A', 10, '20100101';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1, 'A', 20, '20110101';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 1, 'B', 30, '20120101';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 2, 'C', 40, '20130101';
INSERT INTO @table SELECT 2, 'D', 50, '20140101';
```

Then I use this to determine which customers have had a change of name, plus all the other metrics you needed:

```
WITH Customers AS (
    SELECT
        cusnbr,
        MIN(name) AS old_name,
        MAX(name) AS new_name
    FROM
        @table
    GROUP BY
        cusnbr
    HAVING
        COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1),
LoadNumbers AS (
    SELECT
        cusnbr,
        name,
        MAX(loadnumber) AS loadnumber
    FROM
        @table
    GROUP BY
        cusnbr,
        name),
Groups AS (
    SELECT
        name,
        MAX([date]) AS [date],
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS id
    FROM
        @table
    GROUP BY
        name)
SELECT
    c.cusnbr,
    c.old_name,
    c.new_name,
    l.loadnumber,
    g2.[date]
FROM
    Customers c
    INNER JOIN Groups g1 ON g1.name = c.old_name
    INNER JOIN Groups g2 ON g2.id = g1.id + 1
    INNER JOIN LoadNumbers l ON l.cusnbr = c.cusnbr AND l.name = c.old_name;
```

Results are:

```
cusnbr  old_name    new_name    loadnumber  date
1       A           B           20          2012-01-01
2       C           D           40          2014-01-01
```

I added the old/ new names to make this simpler to follow, but you could just strip out the one you don't need?